# Python extract values of a key from a list of lists of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, arraylist

I have a list of lists of dictionaries. The list is continuously building with new data from a stream.

```
[
  [{'T': 1626610583088, 'p': '12562.12'}, {'T': 1626610583088, 'p': '12562.12'}],
  [{'T': 1626610583088, 'p': '12562.12'}, {'T': 1626610583088, 'p': '12562.12'}, {'T': 1626610583088, 'p': '12562.12'}],
  [{'T': 1626610583088, 'p': '12562.12'}], ....... and so on ]
```

(new lists are creating continuously from the stream)

I need to extract the values from 'p', but keeping format of the lists exactly as they are:

```
[[12562.12, 12562.12], [12562.12, 12562.12, 12562.12], [12562.12], ....... and so on ]
```

Comment: As it's from a continuous stream, we can access the data line by line as strings, right?

Comment: if it's a continuous stream might want to wrap it in a higher-order function, such as `map`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a list comprehension:

```
pValues = [[d["p"] for d in row] for row in data]
```

This iterates through each row of your list of lists of dictionaries, then iterates through each dictionary in the row and gets the value of "p" for each of them. (Note `data` is your list of lists of dictionary)

Answer (score 0):

You can try a regular expression:

```
import re

s = '''[[{'T': 1626610583088, 'p': '12562.12'}, {'T': 1626610583088, 'p': '12562.12'}],
  [{'T': 1626610583088, 'p': '12562.12'}, {'T': 1626610583088, 'p': '12562.12'}, {'T': 1626610583088, 'p': '12562.12'}],
  [{'T': 1626610583088, 'p': '12562.12'}]]'''

results = []
for line in s.splitlines():
    results.append(re.findall("(?<='p': ').*?(?=')", line))
    print(results)
```

Output:

```
[['12562.12', '12562.12']]
[['12562.12', '12562.12'], ['12562.12', '12562.12', '12562.12']]
[['12562.12', '12562.12'], ['12562.12', '12562.12', '12562.12'], ['12562.12']]
```

Where the

```
for line in s.splitlines():
```

will be replaced with your continuous stream.